# How to count rows of a column by depending on same values of another column?

Tags: mysql

I have five columns in a table called `tbl_enrolments(id, student_id, semester_id, unit_id, date)`. Here I just need to count the number of same `unit_id` according to same `semester_id` from this table. This is how I've tried so far..

```
SELECT e.unit_id, COUNT(e.unit_id) as count, 
       u.unit_title, 
       u.unit_name, 
       s.sem_name 
FROM tbl_enrolments e
INNER JOIN tbl_unit_of_study u
    ON e.unit_id = u.id
INNER JOIN tbl_semesters s
    ON e.semester_id = s.id
GROUP BY e.unit_id
```

Here this query is counting all same `unit_id` from all different `semester_id`. But I need to count all same `unit_id` with only same `semester_id`. How can I do that?

My table is like this:

[image: Table - tbl_enrolments]

Comment: Replace the screenshot with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, and show desired answer for this data strictly. Additionally - specify MySQL version.

Comment: I just need to count the number of same unit_id according to same semester_id from the above table. How can I do that?

Comment: @AlArefin Have you tried something like WHERE semester_id = x?
have a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bf7e3/5

Comment: @F. Müller thanks for reply. How can I use WHERE, because there's not only one `semester_id`. There are multiple `semester_id` and I have to count all `unit_id` according to all same `semester_id`.

Comment: @AlArefin "But I need to count all same unit_id with only same semester_id. How can I do that?"
I am a bit confused ... you mean: "select all the unique unit_ids for a given semester?" Like all unique unit_ids for semester 1 for example?

Comment: you mean count duplicate unit_id for a given semester_id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this is what you are looking for and if it helps you-

```
mysql> select semester_id, count(unit_id) from tbl_enrolments group by semester_id;
+-------------+----------------+
| semester_id | count(unit_id) |
+-------------+----------------+
|           2 |              5 |
|           1 |              8 |
|          12 |              2 |
+-------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select semester_id, unit_id, count(unit_id) from tbl_enrolments group by semester_id, unit_id;
+-------------+---------+----------------+
| semester_id | unit_id | count(unit_id) |
+-------------+---------+----------------+
|           2 |       3 |              3 |
|           2 |       1 |              2 |
|           1 |       2 |              2 |
|           1 |       6 |              2 |
|           1 |       4 |              4 |
|          12 |       1 |              1 |
|          12 |       6 |              1 |
+-------------+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select semester_id, unit_id, count(unit_id) from tbl_enrolments group by semester_id, unit_id having semester_id = 2;
+-------------+---------+----------------+
| semester_id | unit_id | count(unit_id) |
+-------------+---------+----------------+
|           2 |       3 |              3 |
|           2 |       1 |              2 |
+-------------+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select semester_id, unit_id, count(unit_id) from tbl_enrolments group by semester_id, unit_id having semester_id = 2 and unit_id = 3;
+-------------+---------+----------------+
| semester_id | unit_id | count(unit_id) |
+-------------+---------+----------------+
|           2 |       3 |              3 |
+-------------+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: +1 You were faster. I think it is option 2 that he was looking for. :)
Here I have created a simple db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qqA7yWFudT8JUiNa4DMaPG/0 for those who want to play around.